# What is the accepted approach to diagnose a healthy http call?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm tryin to provide a healthy stream of data to a service endpoint, it suppose to get a stream, do its magic and return a transcription. It did for a while, but sporadically and eventually it kept giving me the same exception.

I'm using the SDK the service provider provided with a local azure function in .NET6.
I'm testing the requests with POSTMAN. I wrote 2 methods , one for IFormfile that I convert to a stream and one for a URL source that is a stream, but the error is the same:

"Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.."

Their client is based on a HttpClient.

Please, is there a way for me to examine if my code is proper, or if my call is okay?
The error began showing up as of last week. I used wireshark to examine the traffic and the only "red" record was from the service provider to my local dev env.Again, keep in mind that all worked, but then this:

**THE ERROR:**

"Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
OR: Here is the more detailed error message..
{
"statusCode": null,
"message": "Error while copying content to a stream.",
"data": {},
"innerException": {
"ClassName": "System.IO.IOException",
"Message": "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..",
"Data": null,
"InnerException": {
"ClassName": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
"Message": "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.",
"Data": null,
"InnerException": null,
"HelpURL": null,
"StackTraceString": null,
"RemoteStackTraceString": null,
"RemoteStackIndex": 0,
"ExceptionMethod": null,
"HResult": -2147467259,
"Source": null,
"WatsonBuckets": null,
"NativeErrorCode": 10054
},
"HelpURL": null,
"StackTraceString": "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.g__CompleteWriteAsync|180_1[TIOAdapter](ValueTask writeTask, Byte[] bufferToReturn)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncChunked[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source, Boolean async)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.g__WaitAsync|56_0(ValueTask copyTask)",
"RemoteStackTraceString": null,
"RemoteStackIndex": 0,
"ExceptionMethod": null,
"HResult": -2146232800,
"Source": "System.Net.Sockets",
"WatsonBuckets": null
},
"helpLink": null,
"source": "System.Net.Http",
"hResult": -2146232800,
"stackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.g__WaitAsync|56_0(ValueTask copyTask)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpContentWriteStream stream, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)\r\n   at Deepgram.Request.ApiRequest.SendHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at Deepgram.Request.ApiRequest.SendHttpRequestAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at Deepgram.Request.ApiRequest.DoStreamRequestAsync[T](HttpMethod method, String uri, CleanCredentials credentials, StreamSource streamSource, Object queryParameters)\r\n   at Deepgram.Transcription.PrerecordedTranscriptionClient.GetTranscriptionAsync(StreamSource source, PrerecordedTranscriptionOptions options)\r\n   at TranscribeAudioAzureFunction.TranscribeAudio.TranscribeLocalFile(IFormFile audio, String nmsApiKey) in C:\NMS MAIN\AzureSourceControl\nmsRemoteProject\AthensLocal\TranscribeAudioAzureFunction\TranscribeAudioAzureFunction\TranscribeAudio.cs:line 346\r\n   at TranscribeAudioAzureFunction.TranscribeAudio.Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log) in C:\NMS MAIN\AzureSourceControl\nmsRemoteProject\AthensLocal\TranscribeAudioAzureFunction\TranscribeAudioAzureFunction\TranscribeAudio.cs:line 186"
}

**EXECUTION CODE:**

```
    public static async Task<PrerecordedTranscription> TranscribeUrlFile3(string LinkToUrl, string nmsApiKey)
    {

        var credentials = new Credentials(nmsApiKey);
        var deepgramClient = new DeepgramClient(credentials);

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        using (var s = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(LinkToUrl))
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream("tmpAudioUrl", FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                await s.CopyToAsync(fs);
                fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var response = await deepgramClient.Transcription.Prerecorded.GetTranscriptionAsync(
                new Deepgram.Transcription.StreamSource(
                fs,
                "audio/wav"),
                new Deepgram.Transcription.PrerecordedTranscriptionOptions()
                {
                    Punctuate = true,
                    Utterances = true
                });

                return response;
            }
        }
    }
```

I apologize in advance if the question is not clear/formulated enough or not according to your standards, but I'm new to this magnificent world of code. Thank you fellow coders.

Comment: What is the timeout of the REquest? (Postmant uses a infinite timeout FYI)

Comment: The request appears to be HTTPS. Is the certificate valid? Have TLS 1.0 and 1.1 been dropped by the API provider? Does it work with TLS 1.2?

Comment: Does the API have restrictions on datasizes or frequency of requests or something of that kind?

Comment: Thank you guys, ill try to examine these angles.